# Change Menu Item Title programmatically

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to change the title of my menu item but every time the app force closes at start.

```
// Prepares Options Menu//
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Link Variable TotalTime to Physical Item In Layout//
    totalTime = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.totaltime);
    totalTime.setTitle("hi");

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
MenuItem myItem = menu.findItem(R.id.totaltime);
myItem.setTitle("hi");
```

Comment: Good to hear! Please remember to click the checkmark to the left of my answer to mark it as correct!